# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.ws.xd.container.state.config.CellSensor$CellConsumer

Tags: websphere, websphere-8

I have a problem, WAS failed initialization since I rename com.ibm.ws.security.crypto.jar at /opt/was_D85/AppServer/plugins to other name.
I already renamed the jar to it's original name but still failed initialization.

My environment is:
OS: AIX
WebSphere 8.5

The error I'm getting:

[12-01-2015 13:13:50:057 WET] 00000001 WsServerImpl  E   WSVR0100W: An error occurred initializing, server1 [class com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ServerImpl]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.ws.xd.container.state.config.CellSensor$CellConsumer
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:264)
                at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.defineClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:188)
                at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:580)
                at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:550)
                at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:490)
                at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass_LockClassName(ClasspathManager.java:460)
                at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:447)
                at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
                at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:393)
                at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:469)
                at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
                at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:410)
                at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:650)
                at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
                at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:93)
                at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:170)
                at java.lang.J9VMInternals.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
                at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1564)
                at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerHelper.initializeComponent(ContainerHelper.java:1060)
                at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerHelper.initializeComponents(ContainerHelper.java:901)
                at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.initializeComponents(ContainerImpl.java:776)
                at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.initializeComponents(ContainerImpl.java:750)
                at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ServerImpl.initialize(ServerImpl.java:333)
                at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.bootServerContainer(WsServerImpl.java:336)
                at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.start(WsServerImpl.java:267)
                at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.main(WsServerImpl.java:730)
                at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServer.main(WsServer.java:59)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
                at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.launchMain(WSLauncher.java:234)
                at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.main(WSLauncher.java:96)
                at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.run(WSLauncher.java:77)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
                at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.callMethodWithException(EclipseAppContainer.java:587)
                at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:198)
                at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
                at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
                at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
                at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
                at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:340)
                at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:282)
                at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:981)
                at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.launchEclipse(WSPreLauncher.java:379)
                at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.main(WSPreLauncher.java:150)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.ws.xd.container.state.config.CellSensor$CellConsumer
                at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:506)
                at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
                at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:410)
                at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:650)
                ... 55 more

Can somebody help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by cleaning the WAS caches.